# Graphical Artifacts in iMac

Tags: macos, imac, startup, gpu

My 2009 27" iMac i7 has several problems, however, the main one is the visual artifacts. They are large areas of black and grey bars, and text displays erratically. Spacing is also affected - the apple menu and all the toolbars are on top of each other

They don't show in safe mode, and the machine is still responsive (albeit very slowly) in normal mode. [image: this] is what the screen looks like.

Trying to open apps causes it to partially open like this: 
[image: text edit shouldn't look like this.]

I can't run AHT because I no longer have the original disks - I'm going to try the github copy linked shortly. 
I believe the problem is related to my graphics card, since the symptoms are similar to those affected by faulty graphics cards in the 2011 model. 
However, that doesn't explain why the issues would vanish in safe mode.

Comment: Have you since been able to resolve this issue?

Comment: No, the Mac was destroyed in an unrelated accident and recycled.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you had to recycle it... If you encounter this issue again I encourage you to check out the solution I posted here: [How To Resolve Finder Graphical Errors on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297227/197131)