# How To Resolve Finder Graphical Errors on macOS

Tags: finder, macos, graphics, high-sierra

I've had a very strange Finer error caused by recent macOS High Sierra betas that affected Macs running macOS 10.13 as well as macOS 10.12 Sierra. This error causes an entire Finder window to show visual artifacts when opening certain folders on either an APFS or HFS+ volume.  After moving the cursor or the affected Finder window, the window may look something like this;

[image]

Attempting to use Disk Utility to repair the affected volume does not resolve this issue, nor does restarting the affected Mac (even in Safe Mode).  Without formatting this disk, how can I prevent Finder from exhibiting this graphical error when opening particular folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This unusual error is very easy to resolve:

1. To resolve the error, first open the affected folder so that a Finder window is exhibiting the unexpected visual errors.
2. Select Finder's "View" menu, then "Clean Up"[image]
3. If "Clean Up" is unavailable or does not resolve the issue, hover over "Arrange By" then select "Name"[image]

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't solve the problem. :(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about that! To get more information, what is the format of the volume that is exhibiting this issue? Have you attempted using Safe Mode, as well as running First Aid on this volume?