# Graphic corruption in Finder when opening specific directories

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, graphics, bug

Since yesterday, my MacBook started to have rendering issues in the Finder app when I open specific directories.

I managed to fix some of them by removing the .DS_Store file in those directories. But now I have one that occurs every time.

[image: Graphic corruption in finder]

Do you guys have an idea of how this can be fixed ?
I bought this macbook one week ago so I don't know what to think..

---

```
MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)
2,9 GHz Intel Core i7
16 Go 2133 MHz LPDDR3
Radeon Pro 560 4 Go
Intel HD Graphics 630 1536 Mo
Mac OS High Sierra 10.13 (17A405)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a solution here: [How To Resolve Finder Graphical Errors on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297227/197131)

If you try that solution, Let me know how it works for you!

Comment: Please do not link an answer but instead flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: The reason I didn't do that is because the linked answer is one that I posted in a Q&A format.

Comment: It’s as valid an answer as any.